# How to retrieve comments using Megaparsec?

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, parsec, megaparsec

I'm printing an AST in order to format the source file, from which the AST is generated using Megaparsec. Comments are missing from the AST, but I intend to keep them after reformatting. Is there a way in Megaparsec to obtain all comments (for both line and block comments) annotated with source info, either [inside AST as a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432341/preserving-comments-in-text-parsec-token-tokenizers) or outside separately as done in [Language.Haskell.Exts.Annotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392546/pretty-print-haskell-source-code-with-comments)?

Comment: What is wrong with the first approach? Without looking at the source code I’m not sure how Megaparsec handles comments if you give it a comment parser, but I’ve an inkling that it just strips them. So the right thing to do would be to modify your AST to include comments and give a parser that never succeeds to Megaparsec for the comment parser (or Nothing if it takes a Maybe). This is left as a comment since I didn’t research what Megaparsec does.